# scanning my site for JavaScript/XSS vulnerabilities

Tags: xss, javascript, vulnerability-scanners

It have had a report that my site may have a security issue and there is some JavaScript loading 10 times per second.

```
www.ayrshireminis.com
```

Is there anyway that I can "scan" my site to check if there is any vulnerable JavaScript, or JavaScript that may have been modified maliciously in some way?

The excessive JavaScript loads (10 times per second) has led to my site being blocked by a Systems Administrator, possibly automatically, as it was causing issues on their network.

Comment: For a quick check, [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#url) can scan a URL for you, but it won't spider the entire site.

Comment: Repeatedly loading a page has nothing to do with XSS.  You should fix the page -- but you should probably also migrate this to Stack Overflow, as this is not relevant to IT Security.

Comment: If my answer helped, could you accept it, or tell me what more you need to know?

Answer (score 4):

It's not every 10 seconds, it's every 30.

Using Chrome developer tools I can see that the script jquery-1.3.1.js at line 3511 (`xhr.send(s.data);`) keeps trying to load a page (getSearch.php) that doesn't exist (404 not found).

The script that is utilising the jQuery is controller.js which contains the line `timer = setTimeout('getSearch()', 30000);`. You'll need to fix up that script to stop it.

Just out of interest; why aren't you using a minified version of jQuery?